# UITabBarController is not fitted to the screen in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have been implemented UITabBarController programmatically. Functionality works fine but the UITabBarController is not fitting inside the screen.

here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let tabBarCnt = UITabBarController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tabBarCnt.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    
    createTabBarController()
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    addHeightConstraintToTabbar()
}

func addHeightConstraintToTabbar() -> Void {
    let heightConstant:CGFloat = self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom + 49.0
    tabBarCnt.tabBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightConstant).isActive = true
}

  func createTabBarController() {

    let firstVc = UIViewController()
    firstVc.title = "First"
    firstVc.view.backgroundColor =  UIColor.red
    firstVc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "HomeTab"), tag: 0)

    let secondVc = UIViewController()
    secondVc.title = "Second"
    secondVc.view.backgroundColor =  UIColor.green
    secondVc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "Location", image: UIImage(named: "Location"), tag: 1)

    let controllerArray = [firstVc, secondVc]
    tabBarCnt.viewControllers = controllerArray.map{ UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: $0)}

    self.view.addSubview(tabBarCnt.view)
 }

}
```

Result screenshot [image]

Comment: I would say that you defined the height of the tab bar not its position.

Comment: @PtitXav How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
tabBarCnt.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```